# Is there any possibility to skip sub category from the product url?

Tags: magento, url, product

I need to change the product url in magento.I need to skip the sub category name from the product url .

Answer (score 0):

`System->Configuration->Catalog->Search Engine Optimization` and set `"Use category path for product urls"` to `No`!

Have fun!

Comment: I believe harleen needs solution for a scenario where category name appears in the url but sub category is avoided. Eg. domain.com/cat-name/product-name.html instead of domain.com/cat-name/sub-cat-name/product-name.html